# MissingRefError - json schema remote REST Webservice enum using $ref doesnt resolve reference to the remote json

Tags: json, forms, rest, jsonschema, ref

I'm using a **[Angular6-json-schema-form](https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form)** to generate Angular Forms from JSON Schemas.

I'm trying to fill an enumeration of the schema from a remote REST webservice using references "**$ref**" but i'm getting the MissingRefError.

Here's my schema:

```
{
"$id": "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c7ff2e833000000338484c2.json#",
"title": "A rather large form",
"type": "object",
"properties": {
  "noenum": { "$ref": "#/definitions/largeEnum" }
}
}
```

the JSON Inside the link have the following:

```
{ 
"definitions": {
"largeEnum": {
  "type": "string",
  "enum": [
    "option #0",
    "option #1",
    "option #2",
    "option #3",
    "option #4"
  ]
}
}
}
```

If i do it locally like this, it works:

```
{
"definitions": {
  "largeEnum": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
        "option #0",
        "option #1",
        "option #2",
        "option #3",
        "option #4"
    ]
  },
  "title": "A rather large form",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "noenum": {"$ref": "#/definitions/largeEnum" }
   }
}
```

Please see the screenshot for the error

[image: Error From Console]

I need to make it work Remotely from a hosted json file or a REST endpoint.

Comment: "the JSON Inside the link have the following:" - What link? Can you explain what you mean by this please?

Comment: "If i do it locally like this, it works:" - If you do WHAT locally? Can you provide some code to demonstrate specifically what you are doing locally please?

Comment: @Relequestual I mean the references '$ref' to /definitions/largeEnum locally ( definitions is provided on the same schema.) The json inside the external link now (mocky.io) on the '$id' property. How come you don't see the code ( json schemas and screenshot of error ) i just provided

Comment: I can see the error just fine. I want to see the code you have written and are running, as this will show me what you have actually done, rather than what I think you may have done.

Comment: Looks like Erwin may be correct. What is it you think `$id` does? `$id` is used to identify the current schema, as per Erwin's answer.

Comment: If I can see your code, it might show what implementation you are using, which may mean I can then determin the implementations behaviour on external references, and tell you if what the answer below has suggested will work for you or not. Implementations do not need to assume that the reference you've provided is a network addressable URL (As in, it might not work if you put it in your browser).

Comment: It looks like the functionality you expect is not currently implemented for the library you're using: https://github.com/hamzahamidi/Angular6-json-schema-form/issues/92

Comment: Well now you understood that the code you were looking for is inside the library! Thank you for your help. Can you suggest any libraries for generating forms from schema which support that functionality (external $ref resolving ). Thanks

Comment: Well no. It would have been useful to show "I'm passing the schema into the form function" code so others can replicate your problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: We maintain a list of Web UI generation libraries that use JSON Schema, although I can't recommend any specifically: http://json-schema.org/implementations.html#web-ui-generation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment, it looks like you think that $id resolves a remote reference. That's not correct though; `$id` *defines* way in which you can refer to the *current* schema.

Instead you need to use the `"$ref"` keyword to refer to a remote schema.

(Whether your validator actively retrieves the remote URL, or requires you to include the content of that schema yourself, is up to the validator implementation.)

You could do:

```
{
    "title": "A rather large form",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "noenum": {
            "$ref": "http://www.mocky.io/v2/5c7ff2e833000000338484c2.json#/definitions/largeEnum"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. $ref to external links is not supported by the library i'm using "(Whether your validator actively retrieves the remote URL, or requires you to include the content of that schema yourself, is up to the validator implementation.)"

Comment: Can you suggest alternative libraries or a method to implement the $ref for external schemas functionality